# How I can use grok instead of if/else conditions?

Tags: logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, filebeat

I have following log-lines for example:

```
Fri Jul 24 01:48:47.572 2020 Failed to fetch database name
Fri Jul 24 01:48:47.572 2020 Failed to fetch database name
Fri Jul 24 01:48:47.572 2020 Unable to connect with database
```

Now I want to differentiate if it is "Failed to fetch database" or "Unable to connect with database". In the first case I want to add the field "Severity = high" an in the other case "Severity = low". But I dont´t want to do it with multiple if/else conditions, because the performance won´t be good (I have many other cases - not only this two). So I wanted to do it with multiple groks like:

```
grok {
   tag_on_failure => []
   match => {"errormessage" => "^%{DATA}Failed to fetch database name%{DATA}" }
}
```

But this pattern isn´t working. Can anyone help me????

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do with this grok? Just tested and it is matching, but it does nothing because you are not creating any field from it. Also, multiple if/else conditions will probably perform way better than multiple groks. Grok can be very bad performance wise depending on the number of events and the grok pattern, I would say that grok should be the last resort for parsing, you can try the `dissect` filter first for example, but you need to explain what is the result you are expecting.

Comment: I don't think using grok to add conditional fields is the way this filter is meant to be used. Rather first use grok (or better [dissect](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-dissect.html)) to retrieve the log fragment that interests and put it in a field, then use a if/else condition on this field to add your severity field.

Comment: If you use grok to parse out the message you can use a translate filter to do a lookup for the severity based on the message.

Comment: @leandrojmp I have thousands of different logmessages and I want to add a field "severity" with a value depending on which errormessage it is. So therefore I have to split the logfile in the different messagetype and add the value for severity for each. And I thought if I add multiple if/else conditions the performance will be bad..